# Java: implicit type conversion, or implicit toString() invocation

Tags: java, scala, aspectj, spring-aop, implicit-conversion

In my Java application I created methods that return [`Either<String, T>`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Data-Either.html) objects.

This is because in some places I invoke these methods as the parameter of (3rd party) methods that expect a String parameter as input.
While in other places I invoke these methods as the parameter of (3rd party) methods that expect some other parameter type (T) as input.

So depending on the place where I invoke the methods that I created, the code looks like:

```
their.thirdPartyExpectsString(my.calculateEither().getLeft());
their.thirdPartyExpectsString(my.calculateEither() + "");
```

or

```
their.thirdPartyExpectsDouble(my.calculateEither().getRight());
```

(I defined `Either.toString()` as `Either.getLeft()`).

Pay attention, I cannot change the 3rd party code (anyway not without bytecode manipulation), and I would like to keep my design in which I return `Either` from my methods.

Is there a way to simplify my code and make it look like

```
their.thirdPartyExpectsString(my.calculateEither());
their.thirdPartyExpectsDouble(my.calculateEither());
```

I.e., not having to add the `getLeft()/getRight()` or `+ ""` all the time?

Actually, it does not bother me much if I will have to do

```
their.thirdPartyExpectsDouble(my.calculateEither().getRight());
```

because I don't have to do it often. But I would like to get rid of the need to call `getLeft()` or `+ ""` when `my.calculateEither()` returns a `Left` (a String).

Given an `either`, it's not hard to see if it represents `Right` or `Left`, simply by checking which side has a `null`.

But the problem is with the type conversion, i.e. the compilation error when `thirdPartyExpectsString()` expects a `String` but gets an `Either`.

I was able to catch the return value of `my.calculateEither()` by AspectJ but I could not see a way how to use something like `@AfterReturning` advice to make the compiler understand that I want to return `my.calculateEither().getLeft()`, i.e a `String`....

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not really sure understood the issue, but how about using generic method instead of Either<String, T>?
ex.)
public <T> T calculate() {...}

Comment: Your `Either` wrapper is custom class? Then it's easy to introduce implicit conversion to double. That would be awkward with util.Either.

Comment: @Satoshi What I described as `my.calculateEither()` is already a generic method, with a generic parameter T (since String is a fixed type). But anyway with your signature, regardless of where inside T you hide the String value - because you call it where a String parameter is expected, you will have to do something like `t.getString()` or `t + ""`.

Comment: @som-snytt This application is written in Java. :(

Comment: This whole design idea is broken IMO. If you do not want type safety, do not use Java. And as much as I love AOP, this is not an appropriate reason to use it.

Comment: @kriegaex Generally you are right. In this specific case I mitigate the type safety issue by making sure automatically that each `Either` instance is used only in the expected methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following method to your implementation of the `Either` class:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public <T> T whichever() {
    return (T) (isLeft() ? getLeft() : getRight());
}
```

Note that I'm purposefully ignoring the warning about the unchecked cast, and indeed will cause a `ClassCastException` if you use it in a place where the external API you interface with expects a *left* value but you invoke it on an `Either` instance which contains a *right* value. This method will do an *implicit cast* based on where you use it. It will cast to a T type where you pass it to another method which expects an argument of type T or you try to assign the method return value to a variable of type T.

So the following demo code:

```
Either<String, Double> containsString = Either.<String, Double>left("first");
Either<String, Double> containsDouble = Either.<String, Double>right(2d);

their.expectsString(containsString.whichever());
their.expectsDouble(containsDouble.whichever());
their.expectsDouble(containsString.whichever());
```

will work well in the first invocation and will cause a `ClassCastException` in the third invocation, just an one would expect, because we consider it as an illegal use case.

In conclusion, it's nice to know that it will work in all places where the T type to which we are implicitly casting is assignable to the actual value contained by the `Either` object. Unfortunately, **you will only find out at run time**, should this not be the case.

Comment: Wow, a really clever maneuver. It's almost implicit type conversion. :) Bravissimo!

Comment: @rapt Yea, that's the most I could come up with. I was thinking about AspectJ based solutions as well, but I couldn't see a way to do it. It might be possible with direct bytecode manipulation though.

Comment: For me, your idea is better than the AspectJ way. Since it does not require complicating the compilation process. As for the type safety issue - well, in this specific application the creation of `Either` as either `Left` or `Right`, as well as where to use them, is done automatically, so the benefit of the simpler code outweighs the risk of misuing my code. I also posted a follow up on this topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35974005

Comment: It actually has a name:) https://www.quora.com/Why-didnt-Java-support-adding-methods-to-objects-at-runtime

Answer (score 0):

Add a helper method. Since you cannot add new methods to `their`, you have to add a `static` to a class of your own.

Pseudo-code:

```
public static void thirdParty(Their their, Either either) {
    if (either.isLeft())
        their.thirdPartyExpectsString(either.getLeft());
    else
        their.thirdPartyExpectsDouble(either.getRight());
}
```

You can now call:

```
MyHelper.thirdParty(their, my.calculateEither())
```

Comment: It would be difficult in my case since `thirdPartyExpectsDouble` and other methods in `Their` also return `Their`, and `Their` has a many such methods. My calls look like `their.expectsString_1(..).expectsString_4(..).expectsString_2(..).expectsString_9(..)...` So my Helper class would be very large.