# Java: Partially applied generic classes - how to eliminate redundant type parameters?

Tags: java, generics

In my Java application I created methods that return [`Either<A, B>`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Data-Either.html) objects.

However the type I really use is `Either<String, T>`, i.e. `String` is always the left type parameter, while the right parameter can be any type.

Here is the [functionaljava](http://www.functionaljava.org/) `Either` implementation I am using:

https://github.com/functionaljava/functionaljava/blob/master/core/src/main/java/fj/data/Either.java

Here `Either` is defined as:

```
public abstract class Either<A, B>
```

To make my code less verbose, I would like to create a generic class `LeftAppliedEither<T>`, which will represent an `Either` in which the left type parameter is set to be String.

So I guess the way to do it is:

```
public abstract class LeftAppliedEither<T> extends Either<String, T> {}
```

However this does not work.

First, `Either` cannot be extended by me since its only constructor is defined as `private`.

Second, let's assume I have solved the first problem by simply copying `Either`'s code into my code (let's call it `MyEither`) and removing the private constructor (and solving some minor compilation errors).

So I have the following class in my code:

```
package fj.data;

//import ....

public abstract class MyEither<A, B> {
    //  private MyEither() {
    //
    //  }

    //the rest of the code is more or less like in the original Either

}
```

Still, I would have the following problem:

I cannot write the following code:

```
LeftAppliedEither<Integer> hello = LeftAppliedEither.left("hello");
```

I only can do things like:

```
MyEither<String,Integer> hello = LeftAppliedEither.left("hello");
```

Well, that defeats the whole reason I was making this change - I wanted not to be required to use in my code the generic type with two parameters, since specifying the left `String` is redundant.

Are there better and more elegant ways to achieve this, other than rewriting the whole `LeftAppliedEither` class?

Comment: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp02216/

Comment: Either is, as you said yourself, not possible to extend. If the only issue really is that you need to type <String,... > whenever declaring, well, tbh I fail to see the big issue really?

Comment: @Oliver Charlesworth Thanks, a good article.

Comment: @JHH It's not crucial, but the "left is always a `String`" requirement is due to a constraint imposed by a 3rd party framework. If it changed in the future, so many other things would break, that in practical terms mentioning the String type is redundant. For me it's easier to create from scratch my own type with only the `Right` as a type parameter, I only need a few of the `Either`'s implemented methods. However here we see an implemented and maintained library, so I was asking myself, am I trying to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are having here is a static method:

```
LeftAppliedEither<Integer> hello = LeftAppliedEither.left("hello");
```

This static method is not affected by inheritance. As you can see in the code, it brings its own generics. So inheritance does not help you here:

```
/**
 * Construct a left value of either.
 * @param a The value underlying the either.
 * @return A left value of either.
 */
public static <A, B> Either<A, B> left(final A a) {
    return new Left<A, B>(a);
}
```

So basically what you need do is to refactor the complete either-class to replace each "A" by a String and remove all "A" in the generic-parameters as shown in this example:

```
/**
 * Construct a left value of either.
 * @param a The value underlying the either.
 * @return A left value of either.
 */
public static <B> MyEither<B> left(final String a) {
    return new MyLeft<B>(a);
}
```

Unfortunately there is not much more what you can do (except the obvious, just write the "String" each time as mentioned in the comments. It may be redundant, but it also helps you clearly to understand the code. So I fell it is useful)